# Edge Extension with NativeMessaging

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge, browser-extension

I have an edge extension with native messaging support where it communicates with uwp application running in the system. Is it mandatory to have extension packaged within the appx folder of uwp app. if not then how can we upload the extension in edge extension store.

I followed the secureInput sample:

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Extensions-Demos/tree/master/SecureInput

They are putting extension within the Appx folder of UWP application. how will I upload extension in edge extension store.

Answer (score 0):

To make an Extension communicate with a UWP App - the Extension and certain runtime components of UWP has to be packaged in the same Appx Package. Please read the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging

Also, it will be much easier to create a Store eligible package through Visual Studio.